# How to build a Visual Studio project when debugging another Visual Studio project in VS 2019?

Tags: c#, debugging, build, dependencies, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio project, A, that is dependent on another project B. Project A gets built and another project, C, uses project A's DLL. Project B is dependent on project C so I can't make project A a dependency of C because I would create a circular dependency. I am primarily working on project A, and I would like to automatically re-build Project A every time I debug project C. Is there some way that project A can get built automatically when I debug project C?

I have tried removing the circular dependency by removing project B from project A's dependencies but it is required if it ever gets built independently of project C.

Comment: I don't think this will cause a circular dependency. You should be able to load all three projects in one solution and reference the DLLs without issue. Have you actually tried this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused--are all three projects part of the same solution? If so then you can specify the build order and build dependencies between the projects in the solution properties.

You should not have to rebuild project A every time you debug project C, unless you have also made changes to project A. As long as project A's DLL is where it's supposed to be, project C should run just fine.

Comment: According to your description I cannot reproduce the error of circular dependency. Maybe you can provide the content of each project's dependencies in your solution to help reproduce this issue?

Comment: @MargaretSchrayer, sorry didn't make it clear that I am running project C in debug mode but I am working on project A. So all the changes I am making are in project A, I just would prefer to have project C rebuild project A every time I run it in debug mode to not have to do it manually. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @JuanR Yes when I load project C, all the solutions are loaded (A, B, and C). Then, when I go to the dependencies of project C and try to add project A I get the error message, "This dependency cannot be added because it will create a circular dependency."

Comment: @JuanR after diving deeper into this I realized that you are right, my question doesn't actually show a circular dependency. For the clarity of the question I was simplifying down the projects, there are actually 6 solutions in the project and the dependencies are a bit messy, and it turns out project A is dependent on a, project D a different project than the ones I have included above, and project D is dependent on Project C. That's where the circular dependency is coming from. Thanks for pointing this out, my fault for not having gone deep enough into the dependencies. I have edited my Q.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT, yea I realized that I hadn't gone deep enough into the dependencies of the other projects. In simplifying down the answer to not include the dependencies of six solutions I messed up and didn't actually describe the correct circular dependency.

Comment: Maybe  you can build ProjectA Programmatically inProjectC like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640571/how-to-build-c-sharp-project-programmatically).